# Flutter's ListView.builder with custom controller will not respond to PageUp/PageDown key events on the web

Tags: flutter, web, scroll

If I create a long list in Flutter Web with a ListView.builder, I get the mouse wheel events and the PageUp/PageDown keyboard events working fine.  If I specify a custom ScrollController, the PageUp/PageDown keyboard events are no longer captured.  How can I fix that?  Here's a simple example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late ScrollController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 500,
              controller: _controller, // will not respond to PageUp, PageDown
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Text('Item $i'))),
    );
  }
}
```

If you comment out the `controller: _controller` line, the PageUp/PageDown presses work.

Is this a bug?  If not, what do I need to do to my custom controller to respond to PageUp/PageDown?

Thank you for your help,
Tony

Comment: It is working in my case, try `flutter clean` and run again.

Comment: I did and it does not work.  I'm using Flutter 2.5.3 stable for the web.  Thanks